# always loading page in browser in ASP.NET Web Form using async/await

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am using ASP.NET Web Form to send two emails and once both emails are sent, I am deleting the file from the system. My code is using async/await and its working fine in the Console application but when I moved the same code to the asp.net web form, it's sending emails but I am not getting any response after  Task.WaitAll(emailSender1, emailSender2), as a result, the file is not deleted and the browser is always seeing loading. I tried to fix the issue but unable at the end. I need someones help to resolve the issue or any alternate ways that could be accomplished. My code is as below:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Async="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div> 
        <asp:Button ID="btnSendEmail" runat="server" Text="Send Email" OnClick="btnSendEmail_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs Code behind**

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static string filePath = @"C:\Uploads\";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sender mailSender = new Sender();
            mailSender.SendEmail("myfirstemail@gmail.com", "mysecondemail@gmail.com", "Async mail with attachment", "Async mail with attachment body goes here ...", filePath + "TestFile.txt");
            Response.Redirect("Succcess.apsx");
        }
    }
}
```

**Sender.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Sender
    {
        public void SendEmail(string toEmail, string logMail, string title, string body, string attachmentPath)
        {
            var emailSender1 = SendEmailAsync(toEmail, title, body, attachmentPath);
            var emailSender2 = SendEmailAsync(logMail, "Copy of " + title, body, attachmentPath);

            Task.WaitAll(emailSender1, emailSender2);

            // deleting file
            File.Delete(attachmentPath);
        }
        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string title, string body, string attachmentPath)
        {
            // class to hold all values from the section system.net/mailSettings/smtp in app.config
            MailConfiguration smtpSection = new MailConfiguration();
            using (MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage("<" + smtpSection.FromAddress + ">", toEmail))
            {
                mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMsg.Subject = title;
                mailMsg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                mailMsg.Body = body;
                mailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachmentPath) && File.Exists(attachmentPath))
                {
                    Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
                    mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                }
                using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtpClient.Timeout = 1000000;
                    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMsg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MailConfiguration.cs**

```
public class MailConfiguration
    {
        private SmtpSection smtpSection = (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp")) as SmtpSection;

        public string ConfigurationFileName
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return smtpSection.ElementInformation.Source;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }

        public string FromAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return smtpSection.From;
            }
        }

        public string Host
        {
            get
            {
                return smtpSection.Network.Host;
            }
        }

        public int Port
        {
            get
            {
                return smtpSection.Network.Port;
            }
        }

        public int TimeOut
        {
            get
            {
                return 2000;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "From: [" + FromAddress + "] Host: [" + Host + "] Port: [" + Port + "]";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it _without_ `Async="true"` in the View?

Comment: Yes, I did and it's giving an exception "InnerException = {"An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that t..." if Anync="true" is not included.

Comment: You really shouldn't mix this async and non-async code. Go all async or no async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)  I came to know that the Console application uses a thread pool SynchronizationContext while GUI or ASP.NET use a one-chunk-at-a-time SynchronizationContext. It means the major cause of deadlock was because of **Task.WaitAll(emailSender1, emailSender2)**. According to the article, I changed this line of code to **await Task.WhenAll(emailSender1, emailSender2)**. The corrected solution is:

**Default.aspx.cs code behind**

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static string filePath = @"C:\Uploads\";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sender mailSender = new Sender();
            mailSender.SendEmail("myfirstemail@gmail.com", "mysecondemail@gmail.com", "Async mail with attachment", "Async mail with attachment body goes here ...", filePath + "TestFile.txt");
            Response.Redirect("Success.aspx", false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sender.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Sender
    {
        public void SendEmail(string toEmail, string logMail, string title, string body, string attachmentPath)
        {
            var result = ActualEmailSend(toEmail, logMail, title, body, attachmentPath);
        }

        public async Task ActualEmailSend(string toEmail, string logMail, string title, string body, string attachmentPath)
        {
            var emailSender1 = SendEmailAsync(toEmail, title, body, attachmentPath);
            var emailSender2 = SendEmailAsync(logMail, "Copy of " + title, body, attachmentPath);

            await Task.WhenAll(emailSender1, emailSender2);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachmentPath) && File.Exists(attachmentPath))
            {
                File.Delete(attachmentPath);
            }
        }
        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string toEmail, string title, string body, string attachmentPath)
        {
            try
            {
                // class to hold all values from the section system.net/mailSettings/smtp in app.config
                MailConfiguration smtpSection = new MailConfiguration();
                using (MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage("<" + smtpSection.FromAddress + ">", toEmail))
                {
                    mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mailMsg.Subject = title;
                    mailMsg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    mailMsg.Body = body;
                    mailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachmentPath) && File.Exists(attachmentPath))
                    {
                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
                        mailMsg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    }
                    using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        smtpClient.Timeout = 1000000;
                        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMsg);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SendEmail exception: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SendEmail done");
            }
        }
    }
}
```